# Pidgin-Latex has an "Error while reading the generated image!"

Tags: latex, pidgin, chat

I had no errors installing `pidgin-latex` via `apt-get` and pidgin runs fine before and after. The plugin is activated. The only problem I have is that (almost) every time a Latex message should be shown, instead the following message pops up and the text is not converted. For example, after sending the message *$$test$$* this error message popped up:

> Error while reading the generated image!
>
> Datei »/tmp/purpleA0SRPY.png« konnte nicht geöffnet werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

The second paragraph is German and means something like

> File /tmp/purpleA0SRPY.png could not be opened: File or directory not found

This is what my command line I started pidgin with said about it:

```
This is dvipng 1.15 Copyright 2002-2015 Jan-Ake Larsson
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/tmp/purpleOZIFPY.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
No file purpleOZIFPY.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1]
(./purpleOZIFPY.aux) )
Output written on purpleOZIFPY.dvi (1 page, 376 bytes).
Transcript written on purpleOZIFPY.log.
[1]
```

And this is what pidgins log said:

```
(14:44:30) LaTeX: Writing Message: $$test$$
(14:44:30) LaTeX: starting to analyse the message: $$test$$
(14:44:30) LaTeX: Found LaTeX-Code: test
(14:44:30) LaTeX: using '0,0,0' for foreground
(14:44:30) LaTeX: using '255,255,255' for background
(14:44:30) LaTeX: 'latex' started
(14:44:30) LaTeX: 'latex' ended normally with exitcode '0'
(14:44:30) LaTeX: 'dvipng' started
(14:44:30) LaTeX: 'dvipng' ended normally with exitcode '0'
(14:44:30) LaTeX: image creation exited with status '0'
```

But effectively all I get is *$$test$$* instead of the desired rendering output from Latex.